# Number of sentence occurrences in another sentence (in PHP)

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to find the number of sentence occurrences in another sentence

For example (I have):

> Hello brother, I have been waiting to tell you something very
>   important. Good bye brother, I will see you next week

and I am searching for:

> brother, I

This should present me the result of:

> result = 2

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: All you need is `substr_count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "Hello brother, I have been waiting to tell you something very important. Good bye brother, I will see you next week"

// explode the string using delimiter 'brother, I', the no of occurance of 'brother, I' will be one less than than the number of element in resultant array.
eg

$resArr = explode("brother, I","$str");

$ans = count($resArr) -1

//assuming your input string is not starting or ending with delimiter ie 'brother, I' in this case
```

Comment: that makes the base case, if no text in the string then zero occurrence of the string being searched for (it can't be negative right)

Comment: What's the sense of using arrays and explode, if you have just one ready function for that?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) function

```
$str = "Hello brother, I have been waiting to tell you something very important. Good bye brother, I will see you next week";

echo substr_count($str, 'brother, I'); // 2
```

If you need a case insensitive way, just make both strings lowercase or uppercase:

```
echo substr_count(strtolower($str), strtolower('brother, I')); // 2
```